# What is the tightest asymptotic growth rate

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have solved all of them however i have been told there are some mistakes, can somebody please help me

n^4 - 10^3 n^3 + n^2 + 4n + 10^6 =  **O(n^4)**

10^5 n^3 + 10^n =   **O(10^n)**

10 n^2 + n log n + 30 √n = **O(n^2)**

25^n =  **O(1)**

n^2+ n log n + 7 n =    **O(n^2)**

(n^3 + 10) (n log n+ 1) / 3 = **O(n^4  log n)**

20 n^10 + 4^n   = **O(4^n)**

n^2 log n^3 + 10 n^2    = **O(n^2  log n)**

10^20 = **O(1)**

n^2 log (6^2)n =    **O(n^2  log n)**

n log(2n) = **O(n log n)**

30 n + 100 n log n + 10 =   **O(n log n)**

(n+√n) log n^3  = **O(n+√n log n)**

n (n + 1) + log log n = **O(n^2)**

4n log 5^(n+1)  = **O(n log 5^n)**

3^(n+4) =   **O(3^n)**

n^2 log n^2 + 100 n^3 = **O(n^3)**

(n log n) / (n + 10) =  **O(n^2 log n)**

5n + 8 n log(n) + 10n^2 =   **O(n^2)**

2n^3 + 2n^4 + 2^n + n^10 =  **O(2^n)**

Comment: please fix formatting. E.g., "log^n" is not what you want,

Comment: @sds fixed (: thankyou for pointing out

Comment: what is `log n^3`? please add parens

Comment: first of all, we are not here to correct homework, so i dont think anybody here is pinpointing all mistakes u made and correct them for you.
Just some hints: 1) in single parameter terms, there is no "+" in big-o , 2) if n is within the term it is likely that O(1) is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your answers look correct, but you have 25^n = O(1) which looks wrong (unless it's 0.25^n), and also you have (n log n) / (n + 10) = O(n^2 log n) which does not look like the tightest possible bound (I'm assuming you want the tightest possible upper bound function). Also you should never have to add functions in your big-O, unless your original function is taking the sum or max of two functions or something and the two functions have cris-crossing different growth rates at different values of n as n goes to infinity. And that very rarely happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. if you have `n` on the left, you should have it on the right
2. there should not be any `+` operations on the right
3. `log(x^y)` can be simplified